# INotifyPropertChanged Updating Bound Listview/gridview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gridview, inotifypropertychanged

Okay so the problem is that my INotifyPropertyChanged isnt updting the list view n XAML

`DiscoveredData.NetworkedComputersResults = NetworkedComputers;` < this is where it loads the data into the DataContext and then calls the iproperty notify changed.

`ListView_LocalComputers.ItemsSource = DiscoveredData.NetworkedComputersResults;` < using this works fine and i can see all my data however this apparantly not the way to do it.

since i know that i can load the data into the list view using the ItemsSource im thinking the problem is in the XAML.

i would be greatful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Also if you see that i am doing this incorrectly please advise, im fairly new at this coding language and would like to do it the right way

Thank you in advance

```
<ListView Name="ListView_LocalComputers" ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkedComputerResults}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border CornerRadius="2,2,2,2" Width="20" Height="20" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="3,3,3,3">

                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="12" Height="12" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Fill" Margin="2,2,2,2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Local Computers" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ComputerName}">
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>


//Constructor
public NetworkInformation()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = DiscoveredData; //Defines the class to the view
    Discovery();
}
//Method
public void Discovery()
{

    GetIcon Icon = new GetIcon();
    BitmapImage IconOfComputer = null;
    List<DiscoveredComputer> NetworkedComputers = new List<DiscoveredComputer>();
    DirectoryEntry Discover = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://Workgroup");
    BitmapImage On = Icon.LoadIcon(@"/Images/Icons/ComputerOn.ico");
    BitmapImage Off = Icon.LoadIcon(@"/Images/Icons/ComputerOff.ico");
    foreach (DirectoryEntry Node in Discover.Children)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Node.Properties.Count > 0)
            {
                IconOfComputer = On;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            IconOfComputer = Off;
        }
        if (Node.Name != "Schema") { NetworkedComputers.Add(new DiscoveredComputer { Image = IconOfComputer, ComputerName = Node.Name, MyToolTip = "Node Type = " + Node.SchemaEntry.Name }); }
    }
    DiscoveredData.NetworkedComputersResults = NetworkedComputers;
    ListView_LocalComputers.ItemsSource = DiscoveredData.NetworkedComputersResults;
}
private class GetIcon
{
    public BitmapImage IconStorage { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage LoadIcon(String IconPath)
    {
        BitmapImage GeneratedIcon = new BitmapImage();
        GeneratedIcon.BeginInit();
        GeneratedIcon.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,," + IconPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        GeneratedIcon.EndInit();
        IconStorage = GeneratedIcon;
        return GeneratedIcon;
    }
}

public class NetworkData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Property Notify Standard for all classes
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    #endregion

    #region Bound Data To View
    private List<DiscoveredComputer> _NetworkedComputersResults;
    public List<DiscoveredComputer> NetworkedComputersResults { 
        get { return _NetworkedComputersResults; }
        set
        {
            _NetworkedComputersResults = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NetworkedComputersResults");
        }
    }
    #endregion
    public class DiscoveredComputer : NetworkData
    {
        public string ComputerName { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
        public String MyToolTip { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ObservableCollection`. It implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which notifies when a collection changed, not just a single Item.

The items themselves should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` of course...

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a plain `List<T>` to your `ListView`. However this works fine, it will not fulfill the requirement of dynamic updating the list view when items are added / removed.

If you need the dynamic add/remove elements in your `ListView` simply use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of the `List``.

```
private ObservableCollection<DiscoveredComputer> _NetworkedComputersResults;
public ObservableCollection<DiscoveredComputer> NetworkedComputersResults { 
    get { return _NetworkedComputersResults; }
    set
    {
        _NetworkedComputersResults = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("NetworkedComputersResults");
    }
}
```

If all you need is elements be dynamically be added/removed, then the elements in the observable collection do not need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NetworkData 
{
    public NetworkData()
    {
        NetworkedComputersResults = new ObservableCollection<DiscoveredComputer>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<DiscoveredComputer> NetworkedComputersResults{get;set;}
}
```

> DiscoveryMethod

```
public void Discovery()
{

    GetIcon Icon = new GetIcon();
    BitmapImage IconOfComputer = null;
    List<DiscoveredComputer> NetworkedComputers = new List<DiscoveredComputer>();
    DirectoryEntry Discover = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://Workgroup");
    BitmapImage On = Icon.LoadIcon(@"/Images/Icons/ComputerOn.ico");
    BitmapImage Off = Icon.LoadIcon(@"/Images/Icons/ComputerOff.ico");
    foreach (DirectoryEntry Node in Discover.Children)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Node.Properties.Count > 0)
            {
                IconOfComputer = On;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            IconOfComputer = Off;
        }
        if (Node.Name != "Schema") { NetworkedComputers.Add(new DiscoveredComputer { Image = IconOfComputer, ComputerName = Node.Name, MyToolTip = "Node Type = " + Node.SchemaEntry.Name }); }
    }

    //Use Clear and Add .Dont assign new instance DiscoveredData.NetworkedComputersResults=new ....
    DiscoveredData.NetworkedComputersResults.Clear();

    foreach (var item in NetworkedComputers)
    {
        DiscoveredData.NetworkedComputersResults.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.From my personal View it would be good If you create this Discovery method in ViewModel and would Call it from the Constructor of ViewModel . It seems two way communication like you setting property of ViewModel from View thats the job of Binding not code behind

Comment: DiscoveredData.NetworkedComputersResults.Clear(); - error object not set to instance.

Comment: i have replicated this code and still cannot see the items. just wondering should there be somewhere i have to notify the InotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: There is no need for that when you use ObservableCollection.